# Resizing an Array with a Dedicated Method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, resize

I am at my wit's end with this one. I need to create an array and then use a separate method to resize it and then print it using yet another method. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab07 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Variables
    int userSize;
    int newSize;
    int diff;

    //Scanner
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


    do{
        System.out.println("Input an array size: ");
        userSize = kb.nextInt();    
    }while(!(userSize>0));

double[] userNums = new double[userSize];

    System.out.println("Now please enter "+userSize+" numbers.");

    //Gathering Input
    for(int i= 0; i < userNums.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Input a number into your array: ");
        userNums[i] = kb.nextDouble();

    }
    //Print Array
    System.out.println("Here are all the numbers in your array:");
    printArray(userNums);

    //New Size
    System.out.println();

    do{
        System.out.println("Input a new size: ");
        newSize = kb.nextInt(); 
    }while(!(newSize>userSize));
    diff = newSize-userSize;
    System.out.println("You need to add "+diff+" new values.");

    //Resize
    arrayResize(userNums, newSize);

    //New input
    for(int i= userNums.length; i <= newSize; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Input a number into your array: ");
        newArray[i] = kb.nextDouble();
    }
    printArray(newArray);
}

public static void printArray(double[] arr)
{
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
        if(!(j==(arr.length-1)))
            {
            System.out.print(+arr[j]+", ");
            }
        else{
            System.out.print(+arr[j]);
        }
    }   
    System.out.print("]");

}

public static double[] arrayResize(double[] oldArray, int newSize)
{
    double[] newArray = new double[newSize];

    for(int i=0; i<newArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(i<oldArray.length)
        {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
        }
        else
        {
            newArray[i] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    return newArray;
```

I need my result to look like this:

```
Input an array size: 5

Now please enter 5 numbers
Input a number into your array: 10.0
Input a number into your array: 6.5
Input a number into your array: 4.4
Input a number into your array: 0.0
Input a number into your array: 15.0
Here are all the numbers in your array: 
[10.0, 6.5, 4.4, 0.0, 15.0]

Input a new size: 7
You need to add 2 values
Input a number to add to your array: 42.42
Input a number to add to your array: 84.99
Here are all the numbers in your new array: 
[10.0, 6.5, 4.4, 0.0, 15.0, 42.42, 84.99]
```

My problem is when it comes time to call arrayResize. I have no idea how to get the new values into the array and I don't know how I can use it with printArray. I can't move any of the code from one method to another, either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of `arrayResize(userNums, newSize);`. You are returning a value but doing nothing with it, so `userNums` remains the same as it was before the call to your resize method. Try this:

```
userNums = arrayResize(userNums, newSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace the current `userNums` with the resized array just do:

```
userNums = arrayResize(userNums, newSize);
```

In your `arrayResize()` method, there is no need to fill the rest of `newArray` with `0.0`, because this is already the default value when you create a `double[]` array. Also, you only need to loop up to `oldArray.length`, since there are no more elements to add to `newArray` after that.

```
public static double[] arrayResize(double[] oldArray, int newSize) {
    double[] newArray = new double[newSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

You could implement this method easily using `System.arraycopy()`:

```
static double[] arrayResize(double[] oldArray, int newSize) {
    double[] newArray = new double[newSize];
    System.arraycopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, oldArray.length);
    return newArray;
}
```

Example:

```
double[] old = {1.5, 2.5, 3.5};
double[] resized = arrayResize(old, 6);
printArray(resized);
```

Output:

```
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```